# My Website speed performance is failed according to gtmetrix, how i can improve it

Tags: performance

[Site Performance.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZh6w.jpg)

Hello Dears,
So I have this website http://www.primebuild.com.lb/testprimebuild/, I run the test and it failed, any ideas how I can improve the speed.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you're using [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress),

I don't know what theme you're using, but it seems to use a hell of a lot of different stylesheet files. Try checking reviews on the theme to see if you can find an alternative.

Otherwise, you can at least cache some resources using a plugin like [Autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/), here's a great article from Wordpress aubout caching : [Optimization | WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/article/optimization/#browser-caching)

Hope that helped !